# vCloud edge gateway DNAT does not forward requests coming from internal network

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcloud-director

Consider the following configuration:

```
                    ------------------------------- [Remote Client on internet]
                    |
                    |
               (public IP)
              192.171.140.2
                    |
              Edge Gateway
                    |
               192.168.1.1
                    |
                    |
          -----------------------
          |                     |
    192.168.1.2           192.168.1.3
   [Local client]           [Server]
```

- example.com points to 192.171.140.2 which is the public IP of the
  edge gateway
- Server hosts a webserver on port 8080
- Remote client wants to access the server using http://example.com
- Local client wants to access the server using http://example.com

I created the necessary DNAT rule which forwards the requests `192.171.140.2:80->192.168.1.3:8080` which works fine, the external client can access the server. However, `Local client` cannot. It seems the `edge gateway` drops the packets coming from `Local client` and going towards the `server`. Both `Local client` and `Server` can access the internet and both of them can ping `example.com` (192.171.140.2). All firewalls are disabled.

The question: Why `Local client` cannot access `Server` using `http://example.com`?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to configure "NAT Hairpinning". Basically, you need to create DNAT/SNAT rules on both networks connected to edge ( local and external ).

Comment: Please include relevant information in your post. You listed the name of a possible solution, but that doesn't answer the question without a procedure.